# Correct way to write this in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to link several variables from a database into html. All the data is stored in the DB, however I can't figure out how to link the variables through HTML. Below is my code that I have tried, but doesn't work properly.

```
echo '<a href="' + $row["name"] +'">test</a>';
```

I know the code works properly if I just do something like this (it does return the name):

```
echo $row["name"];
```

So why doesn't it work properly with the + $row["name"] + in it? It works perfect as long as I don't try and add data with the +'s.

Thank you!

Comment: In php, you concatenate strings using `.` instead of `+`. So just replace them and it should work.

Comment: + is not a string operator.

Comment: @Rizier123 Your comment might be confusing to some, I know the gist of what you mean, but, for clarity, `echo` is NOT js

Comment: `$test = ['foo' => 'bar'];`

`echo "<a href='http://example.com/{$test['foo']}'>Ololo</a>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct way to write this

```
echo '<a href="'.$row["name"].'">test</a>';
```

Comment: Its right way to do it

Comment: @nl-x I think, because the first post was `echo "test";` which wasn't related to the question at all! And the question was asked many times before already! And this answer doesn't explain anything

Comment: Well that happens if someone tries to be the first to answer at all costs, even if it means answering with something completely irrelevant and editing afterwords

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.` in stead of `+`.

And on a sidenote, if the data in the db isn't yet escaped, also use `htmlspecialchars()` on `$row["name"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
echo "<a href='".$row['name']."'>test</a>";
```

Comment: Really?!!! You posted the exact answer already! Here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805582/3933332 You just deleted it, because you had 3 downV on it or what?!

Comment: @user1114503 this may work for you :)

Comment: @Rizier123 no i added the wrong quotes,thats why i delete my answer and add new.

Comment: Then I can tell you that there is a [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28805675/edit) button to edit you answer!, so that you not have to post every time a new one if you make a change! Oh wait! You already [knew that!](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28669162/revisions), so... why didn't you edited your old answer?

Comment: BTW: On SO we want answers which add some *value*, but this answer is also the same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805503/3933332 So what *value* adds this answer here what the other one doesn't have?!

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).